# Remove MenuItem White Space Inside ComboBox

Tags: wpf, menuitem

I have a menuitem nestled within a combobox and I've not been able to get rid of the terrible white space to the left and right of it.

The code is:

```
<Grid>
<ComboBox Name="SettingsCmbx" Text="Options" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="80" Style="{StaticResource blackGradientComboBox}" Margin="3">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <!--<ComboBoxItem Name="Options" IsEnabled="False" Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">Options</ComboBoxItem>-->
            <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">Guidelines</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">Copy Investigation</ComboBoxItem>
            <MenuItem Name="CurrencySelectMenuItem" Header="Currency" Background="Black" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <MenuItem Name="DollarSelectMenuItem" Tag="36" Header="$ - Dollar" Background="Black" Foreground="White"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Name="PoundSelectMenuItem" Tag="163" Header="£ - Pound" Background="Black" Foreground="White"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">About</ComboBoxItem>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
<TextBlock Name="OptionsTxtBlk" Text="Options" IsHitTestVisible="False" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
 </Grid>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding negative margins on either side. Margin = "-5,0,-5,0"